# Creating sublist from a give list of items

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, numpy

I would say first that **the following question is not for homework purpose** even because i've finish software engineer a few months ago. Anyway today I was working and one friend ask to me this strange sorting problem.

"I have a List with 1000 rows, each row represent a number, and I want to create 10 sub lists each have a similar summation of the numbers from the main list. How can I do that?"

For example I've the main list composed by 5,4,3,2 and 1. It's simple, I create two sub lists
one with 5 and 3 the other with 4,2 and 1 the result of each list it's similar: 8 for the first 7 for the second.

I can't figure it out the algorithm even if know it's simple but I'm missing something.

Comment: Also see [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: You mean you have a list that contains 1000 lists? "rows" is ambiguous here. Or do you mean you have a list with 1000 elements; also how is 8 and 7 similar, unless you mean the difference is 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `A` be the input array. I'll assume it is sorted ascending.

```
A = [2,3,6,8,11]
```

Let `M[i]` be the number of sublist found **so far** to have sum equal to `i`.

Starts with only `M[0] = 1` because there is one list with has sum equals zero, that is the empty list.

```
M = [1,0,0,...]
```

Then take each item from the list `A` one-by-one.
Update the number of ways you have to compose a list of each sum when considering
that the item you just take can be used.

```
Suppose a is the new item
for each j:
    if M[j] != 0:
        M_next[j+a] = M[j+a] + M[j]
```

When you found any `M[j]` which reach 10 during that, you should stop the algorithm.
Also, modify to remember the items in the list to be able to get the actual list at the end!

Notes:

- You can use *sparse* representation for `M`
- This is similar to those Knapsack and subset sum problems.
  Perhaps you might find many better algorithms reading on those.

---

Here is a working code in Python:

```
A = [2,3,6,8,11]
t = sum(A)
M = [0]*(t+1)
M[0] = 1

print 'init M :',M

for a in A:
    for j in range(len(M)-1,-1,-1):
        if M[j] != 0:
            M[j+a] += M[j]
    print 'use',a,':',M
```

And its output:

```
init M : [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
use 2 : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
use 3 : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
use 6 : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
use 8 : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
use 11 : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Take the interpretation of `M[11] = 3` at the end for example;
it means there are 3 sublists with sum equals 11.
If you trace the progress, you can see the sublists are `{2,3,6},{3,8},{11}`.

---

To account for the fact that you allow the 10 sublists to have *similar* sum. Not just exactly the same sum. You might want to change termination condition from "terminate if any M[j] >= 10" to "terminate if sum(M[j:j+3]) >= 10" or something like that.