# Algorithm related to Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem that says you will be given an integer N which is 
 0 <= N <= 150000. You will also be given an array containing integers, with the array length up to 2000.

I want to get sum of the subset of the array that be closest to N or exactly equal N. The problem states that the sum should be either exactly equal to N, but if there is no subset that can reach N exactly, so we should bring the closest, yet less than N. For example:

N = 11  and `Array = { 2 , 3 , 5 , 7 }` the output should be in this case 10
N = 12  and `Array = { 4 , 6 , 9 }` the output should be in this case 10
N = 10 and `Array = { 2 , 3 , 3 , 10 }` the output should be in this case 10

I have tried to solve this with all permutations but it gives me time limit exceed as the input constraint is high. I tried to use Dynamic Programming but the 2D array store give memory limit exceed as `mem[150001][2001]`. I tried to do it in [150001][2] as some tutorials about DP mentioned but I couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964848/creating-sublist-from-a-give-list-of-items) I just answered. I use DP, but didn't need to have a 2D array. Just 1D is enough.

Comment: Certainly you can limit your checks to combinations rather than permutations, which will cut down your time and memory usage.

Comment: What language do you (need to) use? Or do you need pseudocode? Is the given array always sorted? If no, try to sort it, that helps a lot :)

Comment: Java :) or any similar language

Comment: The first part of this problem (decide whether an exact sum exists) is the NP-complete subset sum problem. An efficient solution to the general case would be a major discovery, but there are some good algorithms for special cases. See the wikipedia article [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem] for a start.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Link does not seem to work.

Comment: Formatting didn't come out the way I wanted... but if you stick an `http://` on the front of it, it works. `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution running quite quickly. I didn't do strict timing or memory checks though. My solution is recursive though I don't see how to make it dynamic:

1. Find largest number in Array less than N, add it to the subset
2. Recurse over step 1, subtracting from N the number you just added

   *This gives you a possibly imperfect solution:* 
   if N = 18, Array = {12, 9, 8, 5, 4}, you'll end up with subset answer {12, 5} instead of {9, 5, 4}. You can say that the 'gap' in this solution is `gap = 1`.
3. For each member `m` of the subset, you're going to solve again, setting N to `m + gap`, and Array to the members of the original Array excluding all members of the subset. In our example, we would spawn two more problems: N = 13, Array = {9, 8, 4}, and N = 6, Array = {9, 8, 4}.
4. Take the best solution offered by the previous step, as determined by gap reduction. If the gap in the best solution is less then the gap in the larger problem, replace the targeted number with the subset. In our case N = 13 is solved perfectly by {9, 4}, which targeted the 12, so we replace 12 with {9, 4} giving us {9, 4, 5}.
5. If `gap=0` for this sub problem, we're done.
6. If you don't reach `gap=0`, but did do a replacement, recurse over step 4.
7. If you didn't do a replacement in step 4, you have the best possible solution, you're done.

I did it in a rather ugly C#, though if you want the code, I could clean it up a bit.

**EDIT: Added code**

I tried to cordone off the C# particulars to specific functions. Keeping the thing sorted the whole time is not necessary, and I'm sure you can cut down on memory usage in the ImproveOnGaps function.

To run:

```
void Main()
{
    Problem p = Solvers.GenerateRandomProblem();
    Solution imperfectSolution = Solvers.SolveRecursively(p);
    Solution bestPossibleSolution = Solvers.ImproveOnGaps(s);
}


class Solution
{
    public Problem Problem;
    public int[] NumbersUsed;
    public int n;
    public int[] NumbersUnused;
}

class Problem
{
    public int N;
    public int[] Array;
}

class Solvers
{
    public static Problem GenerateRandomProblem()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int N = r.Next(1500000);
        int arraySize = r.Next(1, 2000);

        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            array[i] = r.Next(1, 15000);

        Problem problem = new Problem
        {
            N = N,
            Array = array
        };

        return problem;
    }

    public static Solution SolveRecursively(Problem p)
    {
        return SolveRecursively( new Solution
        {
            Problem = p,
            n = 0,
            NumbersUnused = SortAscending(p.Array),
            NumbersUsed = new int[0]
        });
    }

    private static Solution SolveRecursively(Solution s)
    {
        if(s.n == s.Problem.N)
            return s;

        for(int i = s.NumbersUnused.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) //
        {
            if(s.n + s.NumbersUnused[i] <= s.Problem.N)
            {
                return SolveRecursively(new Solution
                {
                    n = s.n + s.NumbersUnused[i],
                    NumbersUnused = SkipIthPosition(s.NumbersUnused, i),
                    NumbersUsed =  AddToSortedArray(s.NumbersUsed, s.NumbersUnused[i]),
                    Problem = s.Problem
                });
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static Solution ImproveOnGaps(Solution s)
    {
        if(s.n == s.Problem.N)
            return s;

        int gap = s.Problem.N - s.n;
        List<Problem> newProblems = new List<Problem>();
        foreach (int i in s.NumbersUsed)
        {
            newProblems.Add(new Problem
            {
                Array = s.NumbersUnused,
                N = i + gap
            });
        }

        int newGap = gap;
        Solution bestImprovement = null;
        foreach (Problem p in newProblems)
        {
            Solution tempSolution = SolveRecursively(p);
            if(tempSolution.Problem.N - tempSolution.n < newGap)
                bestImprovement = tempSolution;
        }

        if(bestImprovement != null)
        {
            List<int> usedNumbers = s.NumbersUsed.ToList();
            usedNumbers.Remove(bestImprovement.Problem.N - gap);
            usedNumbers.AddRange(bestImprovement.NumbersUsed);

            List<int> unusedNumbers = s.NumbersUnused.ToList();
            foreach (int i in bestImprovement.NumbersUsed)
                unusedNumbers.Remove(i);

            return ImproveOnGaps(new Solution
            {
                n = usedNumbers.Sum(),
                NumbersUnused = unusedNumbers.ToArray(),
                NumbersUsed = usedNumbers.ToArray(),
                Problem = s.Problem
            });
        }

        return s;

    }

    private static int[] SortAscending(int[] array)
    {
        return array.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
    }

    private static int[] SkipIthPosition(int[] array, int i)
    {
        return array.Take(i)
            .Union(array.Skip(i + 1).Take(array.Length - 1 - i))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static int[] AddToSortedArray(int[] array, int i)
    {
        return array.Concat(new int[] { i }).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray(),
    }


}
```

Comment: I traced it and I see it works well in my examples , going to try if it will work on all cases and won't pass the time limit , and if you could post your code I would be thankful , Thanks

Comment: I found a flaw: N = 51, Array = {25, 24, 18, 17, 16}. My algorithm returns {25, 24}, when the proper answer is {18, 17, 16}. Not sure of a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the link posted by WumpusQ, I think I got something that works. Basically I use the DP method from the link, then start looking backwards from N for a valid sum and return the first one encountered. (in Python)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dpFunc(N, Array):
  # determine range of possible values
  minSum = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [x for x in Array if x < 0], 0)
  maxSum = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [x for x in Array if x > 0], 0)
  # Initialize
  Q = defaultdict(lambda: False)
  for s in xrange(minSum, maxSum + 1):
    Q[(0,s)] = (Array[0] == s)
    for i in xrange(1, len(Array)):
      Q[(i,s)] = Q[(i-1,s)] or (Array[i] == s) \
          or Q[(i-1,s-Array[i])]
  for s in xrange(N, minSum -1, -1):
    if (Q[(len(Array)-1,s)]):
      return s
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but unfortunately I'm not familiar with python :/